# can we have different buttons(or views) for same layout file for diffrent screen size

Tags: android

can we have different buttons(or views) for same layout file for different screen size

Basically I have sliding layout with few buttons, and I have 2 sliding_drawer.xml file (one for small screen and for big screen tablet). I don't want to show all buttons for large screen (tablet).
I did try removing the buttons from sw600dp/sliding_drawer.xml file, it did not work.

Comment: Post your layout and check the [qualifier](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts) used. `layout-sw600dp` should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare buttons in generic layout but not in sw600dp layout, then it will return error. So for the solution you can do one thing.You need to declare same buttons in both layout and by finding the running device is tablet or phone, you can manage visibility.

Firstly, you need to put this to check device is tablet or phone:

```
  boolean isTablet = isTablet(getApplicationContext);

   if(isTablet){
   //To manage visiblity here
   }else{
   //To manage visiblity here
   } 

    public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
            return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                    & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                    >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
        }
```

you can invisible the button which you don't want to show in tablet.